# SQL Firebird implementation in java/ IBSQL

Tags: java, sql, implementation, firebird, jaybird

so tried to put that SQL code into my java-aplication:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
  StRzImRo.Rohstoff, StRo.Bezeichnung,
CAST (SUM(BwLsImAt.Lieferungen * StRzImRo.Menge * StAt.PROD__REZEPTURGEWICHT / Coalesce(StRz.PARM__BEZUGSGROESSE,1))  AS NUMERIC (9,3)) Rohstoffverbrauch_Gesamt FROM BwLsImAt       

JOIN StAt ON (StAt.IntRowId = BwLsImAt.Artikel)
JOIN StRz ON (StRz.IntRowId = StAt.PROD__REZEPTUR)
JOIN StRzImRo ON (StRzImRo.Master = StRz.IntRowId)
JOIN StRo ON (StRzImRo.Rohstoff = StRo.IntRowId)
WHERE StAt.IntRowId > 0
 GROUP BY  StRzImRo.Rohstoff, StRo.Bezeichnung
-- GROUP BY  StRzImRo.Rohstoff, StRzImRo.Menge, StAt.PROD__REZEPTURGEWICHT, Coalesce(StRz.PARM__BEZUGSGROESSE,1)
```

The code is fully funcional and tested in IBSQL but not working in my java-application.
My app does work properly with other code. I get this error:

```
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 266
ON
```

I would be very happy if someone could help me with this problem. Thanks!
P.S.: Sorry for my bad language, but i´m not a native speaker

Comment: You might want to post the code with the query exactly as it is in your Java application. The error suggests there is an `ON` in an unexpected place in your query, and as the query itself looks fine, my guess is the problem is with the way you construct the query in your Java application. There might be some whitespace missing in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes there was some whitespace missing behind "FROM BwLsImAt" in my java-application. Thanks!

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests there is an `ON` in an unexpected place in your query, and as the query itself looks fine, my guess is the problem is with the way you construct the query in your Java application. There might be some whitespace missing in your query.

My guess is that you have something like

```
query = "SELECT * " +
        "FROM table1" +
        "JOIN table2 ON " //.....
```

The missing whitespace will make the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table1JOIN table2 ON ....
```

For the parser, this is perfectly valid until it encounters the `ON` token, which triggers the error. Eg the parser identifies it is a `SELECT` with `*` (all) columns from `table1JOIN` with alias `table2`. During parsing the server doesn't check if the table actually exists, so it doesn't trip over the fact that `table1JOIN` doesn't exist. That is checked after parsing is successfully completed.