# Query Error using Firebird RDBMS with ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, firebird, coldfusion-11, jaybird

So I have Adobe ColdFusion 11 Update 5 installed on a Windows 2012 server. I added a Firebird datasource using the Jaybird 2.2.5 JDBC driver. I created a query using that datasource like so:

```
<cfquery name="rawdata" datasource="RSReport">
    select * from rptpatientstudy 
    where statusorder >= 200 
    and issuer = 'RWHG' 
    and studydatetime >= '2015-01-01' 
    and studydatetime < '2015-04-01';       
</cfquery>
```

but when I run the page, I get a Dynamic SQL error mentioning an unknown token.

Here's the stack trace:

```
org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: Dynamic SQL Error 
SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 2, column 1 RETURNING
at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2092)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2042)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscDsqlPrepare(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:1465)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSHelper.prepareStatement(GDSHelper.java:190)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractStatement.prepareFixedStatement(AbstractStatement.java:1441)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractStatement.internalExecute(AbstractStatement.java:1423)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractStatement.execute(AbstractStatement.java:867)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractStatement.execute(AbstractStatement.java:441)
at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunStatement.execute(JRunStatement.java:359)
at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1479)
at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1229)
at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1159)
at coldfusion.sql.SqlImpl.execute(SqlImpl.java:406)
at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.executeQuery(QueryTag.java:1185)
at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.startQueryExecution(QueryTag.java:814)
at coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:767)
at cfmarla2ecfm1504149200.runPage(C:\inetpub\WebSites\intranet\marla.cfm:1)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:736)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:572)
at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45)
at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:466)
at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:142)
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's a list of the fields in the table:

```
STUDYINSTANCEUID
PATIENTID
PATIENTNAME
STUDYDATETIME
STUDYDESCRIPTION
PRIORITY
READINGPHYSICIAN
REFERINGPHYSICIAN
PERFORMINGPHYSICIAN
TECHNOLOGIST
TRANSCRIPTIONIST
ACCESSIONNUMBER
INSTITUTIONNAME
STATUSORDER
SCHEDULEDBODYPARTEXAMINED
SCHEDULEDMODALITY
UTCOFFSET
HL7BILLED
SCHEDULEDEXAMROOM
PATIENTBIRTHDATE
MODALITIES
BODYPARTS
IMAGES
AGE
SEX
CONFLICT
STUDYID
FILESETID
ISSUER
SCHEDULEDLATERALITY
LOCATION
PROCEDURECODE
DATETIMEREAD
DURATION
FILM
BURNCD
MAIL
COURIER
AUTOFAXLIST
AUTOEMAILLIST
SCHEDULEDRESOURCE
ACCOUNTSTATUS
LANGUAGE
FINANCIALTYPE
STATE
INSURANCEPAYERS
INSURANCEEXPIRIES
COMMENTS
ALLERGIES
CANCELLATIONREASON
CELLPHONE
HOMEPHONE
AUTHORIZATIONNUMBER
DATEOFSURGERY
RECEIVEDTIME
INTERNALVISITID
SMOKINGSTATUS
```

I'm really not sure where this might have come from, and I can't seem to find something directly applicable on Google; most of the results there seem to deal with using derived tables or `SELECT *` in the query.

Comment: Have you had any successful queries with this datasource?   Also, try removing the semi  colon.

Comment: What is your Firebird version?

Comment: @DanBracuk No; the query I present here is actually a simplified version of the first one I tried, which used an INNER JOIN.

Comment: run a very basic query to rule out driver problems.  Something like `select count(*) records from sometable where 1=2`.  Notice the lack of semi colon.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Firebird 2.5

Comment: @DanBracuk Tried `select count(*) from rptpatientstudy where 1 = 2`. Got the same error.

Comment: _most of the results there seem to deal with using derived tables or `SELECT *` in the query_  Am I missing something?  You are using `select *` in the query you provided here and Dan's example does too. Try a simple query and specify the column names to see if that works.

Comment: @Miguel-F Point; don't know how I missed that. This time I tried `select accessionnumber from rptpatientstudy where 1 = 2`. Same error.

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace? The RETURNING seems to suggest it is actually an update or insert that queries for the generated id, but RETURNING is supported since 2.0. What is the dialect of your database? What are the actual columns in this table?

Comment: I'll add the full stack trace in the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I added the full stack trace for the error, using the query `select accessionnumber from rptpatientstudy where 1 = 2`.

Comment: [edited] _scratch my intial comment but still see this other question for a possible similar issue_ - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17834846/1636917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: It is a bug in Jaybird. I have created bug [JDBC-391](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-391) and this has been fixed in [Jaybird 2.2.8](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/releases/tag/v2.2.8).

The `execute` method called in the stacktrace is [`execute(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-int-) which is usually only called for update/insert that should return generated keys. It looks like Cold Fusion always calls it this way (with value `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`).

The implementation that handles generated keys in Jaybird assumes that its internal statement parser throws an exception when confronted with a `SELECT` statement; if that happens the query should be processed unmodified. Unfortunately there is no test for this assumption and the parser actually doesn't throw an exception when errors occur during parsing (they are signaled in a different way). As a result the `SELECT` query is modified by appending a `RETURNING` clause, which is a syntax error when the query is then sent to the server.

I am not sure if there is a workaround for this, except maybe reverting to Jaybird 2.1.6 as this problem has been there since the initial implementation in Jaybird 2.2.0. You could also check if Cold Fusion has any configuration that would modify the way it executes queries.

This has been fixed in Jaybird 2.2.8.

Disclosure: I am one of the developers of Jaybird.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome! I'll try rolling back my Jaybird version.

Comment: @MattGutting I am not entirely sure if using 2.1.6 will fix it though, it might just as well throw a `FBDriverNotCapableException`. It depends on whether Cold Fusion checks for generated keys support before calling this method.

Comment: @MattGutting Jaybird 2.2.8 has been released today, for downloads see https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/releases/tag/v2.2.8